# Where are the "many times" (פעמים רבות) referred to by Maimonides in his commentary on Mishnah Sotah 3:4? Which statement of בן עזאי?

Tags: sources-mekorot, halacha-theory, rambam, mishna, tractate-sotah

The [Mishnah Sotah 3:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Sotah.3.5) states:

> אֵינָהּ מַסְפֶּקֶת לִשְׁתּוֹת עַד שֶׁפָּנֶיהָ מוֹרִיקוֹת וְעֵינֶיהָ
> בּוֹלְטוֹת וְהִיא מִתְמַלֵּאת גִּידִין, וְהֵם אוֹמְרִים הוֹצִיאוּהָ
> הוֹצִיאוּהָ, שֶׁלֹּא תְטַמֵּא הָעֲזָרָה. אִם יֶשׁ לָהּ זְכוּת, הָיְתָה
> תוֹלָה לָהּ. יֵשׁ זְכוּת תּוֹלָה שָׁנָה אַחַת, יֵשׁ זְכוּת תּוֹלָה
> שְׁתֵּי שָׁנִים, יֵשׁ זְכוּת תּוֹלָה שָׁלשׁ שָׁנִים. מִכָּאן אוֹמֵר
> בֶּן עַזַּאי, חַיָּב אָדָם לְלַמֵּד אֶת בִּתּוֹ תוֹרָה, שֶׁאִם
> תִּשְׁתֶּה, תֵּדַע שֶׁהַזְּכוּת תּוֹלָה לָהּ. רַבִּי אֱלִיעֶזֶר
> אוֹמֵר, כָּל הַמְלַמֵּד אֶת בִּתּוֹ תוֹרָה, כְּאִלּוּ מְלַמְּדָהּ
> תִּפְלוּת. רַבִּי יְהוֹשֻׁעַ אוֹמֵר, רוֹצָה אִשָּׁה בְקַב וְתִפְלוּת
> מִתִּשְׁעָה קַבִּין וּפְרִישׁוּת. הוּא הָיָה אוֹמֵר, חָסִיד שׁוֹטֶה,
> וְרָשָׁע עָרוּם, וְאִשָּׁה פְרוּשָׁה, וּמַכּוֹת פְּרוּשִׁין, הֲרֵי
> אֵלּוּ מְכַלֵּי עוֹלָם
>
> When a guilty woman drinks she does not manage to finish drinking before her face turns green and her eyes bulge, and her skin becomes full of protruding veins, and the people standing in the Temple say: Remove her, so that she does not render the Temple courtyard impure by dying there. The mishna limits the scope of the previous statement: If she has merit, it delays punishment for her and she does not die immediately. There is a merit that delays punishment for one year, there is a larger merit that delays punishment for two years, and there is a merit that delays punishment for three years. From here Ben Azzai states: A person is obligated to teach his daughter Torah, so that if she drinks and does not die immediately, she will know that some merit she has delayed punishment for her. Rabbi Eliezer says: Anyone who teaches his daughter Torah is teaching her promiscuity [tiflut]. Rabbi Yehoshua says: A woman desires to receive the amount of a kav of food and a sexual relationship [tiflut] rather than to receive nine kav of food and abstinence. He would say: A foolish man of piety, and a conniving wicked person, and an abstinent woman [perusha], and those who injure themselves out of false abstinence; all these are people who erode the world.

The Hebrew translation of [Maimonides](https://www.sefaria.org/Rambam_on_Mishnah_Sotah.3.4.1?vhe=Vilna_edition&lang=en) commentary on this Mishnah says:

> ומתנוונת שתחלה בחולי השחפת ונעשית כחושה. וכבר אמרתי פעמים רבות כשיש מחלוקת בין החכמים בסברת אמונה אין תכליתו מעשה מן המעשים שאין אומרים שם הלכה כפלוני. ואין הלכה כבן עזאי

1. I am looking for other places the Rambam brings this concept, as pointed out by him - "פעמים רבות".
2. Also, which saying of בן עזאי is the Rambam referring to?

Comment: The statement of Ben Azai is in the previous Mishna.

Comment: מכאן אומר בן עזאי: חייב אדם ללמד את בתו תורה, שאם תשתה, תדע שהזכות תולה לה.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- *Epistle on the Resurrection of the Dead*
- Sefer Hamitzvot Negative Commandment 233
- Commentary to Mishnah  Sotah 3:5
- Commentary to Mishnah Sanhedrin 10:3
- Commentary to Mishnah Shevuot 1:4

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/25880/759

Comment: @DoubleAA I knew you had written about it somewhere....